# Android - keep playing audio with HTML5 javascript when Internet drops - fetch, blob

Tags: javascript, html, audio, preload

I'd like to preload an entire mp3 file so the page keeps working on computer and mobile when Internet drops. I found and tried the following code which appears to work on my Windows 7 desktop, but not my Android. The Android doesn't fail on the fetch statement but appears to fail on the ".then(r => r.blob())" statement. Should r be declared first? Any ideas why android fails. I haven't been able to access the Android console.

```
fetch("https://foo.com/foo2/foo4.mp3")
.then(r => r.blob())   // could be xhr.responseType = 'blob'
.then(blob => {
aud = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
document.body.appendChild(aud);
console.log('Fully loaded and cached until the page dies...')   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload) attribute you can try`

#### preload

> This enumerated attribute is intended to provide a hint to the browser
>   about what the author thinks will lead to the best user experience. It
>   may have one of the following values:
>
> - none: Indicates that the audio should not be preloaded.
> - metadata:    Indicates that only audio metadata (e.g. length) is fetched.
> - auto:    Indicates that the whole audio file can be downloaded, even if the user is not expected to use it. empty
>     string: A synonym of the auto value.
>
> If not set, preload's default
>   value is browser-defined (i.e. each browser may have its own default
>   value). The spec advises it to be set to metadata.